# How to create a nested and bold keywords index?

Tags: formatting, indexing, bold, imakeidx

I want to create an index with nested and formatted (bold) entries with the package `imakeidx`.

The index should look like this:

---

**Graph**, 3

-> **Graph Drawing**, 3, 5

---

but it looks like this:

---

Graph

-> **Graph Drawing**, 3, 5

**Graph**, 3

---

I used the following code, to add the entries to the index:

```
\emph{graphs}\index[keywords]{Graph@\textbf{Graph}}
\emph{graph drawings}\index[keywords]{Graph!Graph Drawing@\textbf{Graph Drawing}}
```

Is it possible to create a nested and bold index with `imakeindx` and if so, how should the code then be written?

---

Update -> Example:

```
%% File encoding: UTF-8
\documentclass[english]{styles/mystyle}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=keywords, title=Keywords Index,columns=1]

\begin{document}

A sentence with the keyword \emph{graphs}\index[keywords]{Graph@\textbf{Graph}} in it.

\clearpage
A sentence with the keyword \emph{graph drawing}\index[keywords]{Graph!Graph Drawing@\textbf{Graph Drawing}} in it.

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Keywords Index}
\printindex[keywords]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It might be worthwhile to provide a Minimal working example [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Have you tried `\index[keywords]{Graph@\textbf{Graph}!Graph Drawing@\textbf{Graph Drawing}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you index entries multiple times, you need to make sure each instance matches exactly. This includes each level of a hierarchical index, so if you do `\index{`*main`}` and `\index{`*main*`!`*sub*`}` the *main* part must exactly match, otherwise they're considered separate items.

In the case of `\index[keywords]{Graph@\textbf{Graph}}` the *main* part is `Graph@\textbf{Graph}` but in `\index[keywords]{Graph!Graph Drawing@\textbf{Graph Drawing}}` the *main* part is just `Graph`. This means that `Graph@\textbf{Graph}` is considered a separate term that doesn't have a sub-entry. The sub-entry instead belongs to `Graph`.

So you need

```
\index[keywords]{Graph@\textbf{Graph}!Graph Drawing@\textbf{Graph Drawing}}
```

Comment: Makes sense, that it needs to match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you - @Nicola Talbot,

```
\index[keywords]{Graph@\textbf{Graph}!Graph Drawing@\textbf{Graph Drawing}}?
```

works perfect.